# Flutter - The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I've been working on this project, and everything worked fine, until, I migrated the packages to null safety and encountered this error. Here's the code:

```
  factory AdminDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AdminDtoFromJson(json);

  factory AdminDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return AdminDto.fromJson(doc.data()!).copyWith(id: doc.id);
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? The problem occurs when it comes to doc.data() parameter. I can't quite put my head into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly cast `doc.data()!` to `Map<String, dynamic>`. Like this:

```
return AdminDto.fromJson(doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>).copyWith(id: doc.id);
```

Or correctly define the generic type of `DocumentSnapshot`, like this:

```
factory AdminDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    return AdminDto.fromJson(doc.data()!).copyWith(id: doc.id);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! Sir, you're a life saver! I spent almost 5 hours trying to solve this error. And I have one more question: does wrapping doc.data() to doc.get(doc.data()!) helps in this case? Because I tried this one and it doesn't return any error

Comment: I am no expert when it comes to firestore, but to me `get()` looks more like a direct accessor of fields in `data`, while `data()` returns the whole dataset. You probably want the latter.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much, Sir ❤️